# Angular circular dependency detected in component

Tags: angular

I have 2 components each of them needs other component to import. when importing it      gives a warning in terminal 'circular dependency detected'.

My components code as follows:

Component 1

```
import { ReservationDateInfoComponent } from 'app/modules/reservation-date-info.component';

    export class RateInfoComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private dialog: MatDialog){}

      openDateInfo(){
        this.dialog.open(ReservationDateInfoComponent, { width: '1000px'});
      }


    }
```

Component 2

```
import { RateInfoComponent } from '../../../core/shared/components/rate-info/rate-info.component';

export class ReservationDateInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog){}

  openRateInfo(){
    this.dialog.open(RateInfoComponent, { width: '1000px'});
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would a modal opoen a modal, that can open the previous modal ? This is a very bad design ! Can you consider changing it ?

Comment: it is step by step form filling process. after filling first modal data click next button open the second modal and closing the first modal. also need to go back to previous modal from the second modal.

Comment: [There is a component for step by step processes](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview), consider using it !

Comment: @trichetriche thanks for the solution,  is there any workaround that can solve in current condition using modals.

Comment: Probably, but I'm not aware of it, as components that depend on each other will necessarily create a circular dependency.

Answer (score -1):

The circular dependency clearly comes, because in the *ReservationDateInfoComponent* you import the *RateInfoComponent*, that is again importing the *ReservationDateInfoComponent*.

The following describes your circle:

*RateInfoComponent* -> *ReservationDateInfoComponent* ->*RateInfoComponent* ....

**Possible Solution**

And **additional component** can import all needed modals and display them in a row. It also sounds like you need to transfer data between the modal-components. This is possible by the use of [Observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables). This way, your third component should subscribe each modal to get its data.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: (Also, I don't think it is a solution but a workaround)

Comment: @trichetriche A change of the application design in my opinion is not really a workaround. There is no other solution to this problem, then to linearize the imports.

Comment: I think you meant application structure ? And it is a workaround, the real solution being to remove the bad design implemented here. But that's semantics, so it's not that important !